# Python - If, elif statements

Tags: python-2.7, loops, if-statement

I've not long started with python and I've looked over a lot of posts on here but just cant seem to work out whats wrong with my code...
If the user types in N or n then surely my elif would kick in but it still plays the  sound and prints out "sound played".
Can anyone help please? Thank you.

```
test2 = raw_input("Would you like to test the sound? Y\N or exit? ")
if test2 == "Y" or "y":
    winsound.PlaySound('C:/Windows/Media/tada.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
    print ("Sound Played")
elif test2 == "N" or "n":
    print ("Test skipped")
elif test2 == "exit":
    print ("Test exit")
else:
    print ("Please choose an option")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Wow, it's like an ultimate duplicate, but 4 answers (and none with _actual_ explanation **why** is this happening) had to be posted. Nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if test2 == "Y" or "y"
```

should be

```
if test2 == "Y" or test2 == "y"
```

Python is evaluating "y" as true

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
elif test2 == "N" or "n":
```

and you mean:

```
elif test2 == "N" or test2 == "n":
```